# Load data from JSON url in HTML table without duplications

Tags: javascript, html

I have created the table, I have parsed the data from the JSON url (in the snippet I changed it to make it work) and now I only want to load unique values. For example "Debra" can be seen twice.

```js
$(function() { 
    var data = [{"id":2.2,"first_name":"Debra","last_name":"Rodriguez","email":"drodriguez0@admin.ch","gender":"Female","ip_address":"90.22.159.108"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Julie","last_name":"Lynch","email":"jlynch1@tumblr.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"54.182.62.180"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Norma","last_name":"Washington","email":"nwashington2@theatlantic.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"70.163.106.64"},
{"id":4,"first_name":"Bobby","last_name":"Castillo","email":"bcastillo3@nbcnews.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"91.202.59.171"},
{"id":5,"first_name":"Henry","last_name":"Chavez","email":"hchavez4@chronoengine.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"32.237.37.185"},
{"id":6,"first_name":"Debra","last_name":"Howard","email":"showard5@stumbleupon.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"17.217.42.49"},
{"id":7,"first_name":"Jason","last_name":"Powell","email":"jpowell6@telegraph.co.uk","gender":"Male","ip_address":"14.81.195.117"},
{"id":8,"first_name":"Sean","last_name":"Burns","email":"sburns7@hp.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"213.164.85.212"},
{"id":9,"first_name":"Jacqueline","last_name":"Gordon","email":"jgordon8@bloglines.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"18.251.62.55"},
{"id":10,"first_name":"Russell","last_name":"Richards","email":"rrichards9@com.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"27.226.59.80"},
{"id":11,"first_name":"Albert","last_name":"Perkins","email":"aperkinsa@hc360.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"243.122.251.248"},
{"id":12,"first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Willis","email":"mwillisb@deviantart.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"252.197.211.230"},
{"id":13,"first_name":"Joan","last_name":"Hamilton","email":"jhamiltonc@weebly.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"204.70.110.117"},
{"id":14,"first_name":"Eric","last_name":"Garcia","email":"egarciad@yahoo.co.jp","gender":"Male","ip_address":"178.221.216.3"},
{"id":15,"first_name":"Frank","last_name":"Olson","email":"folsone@amazon.co.uk","gender":"Male","ip_address":"245.25.170.33"},
{"id":16,"first_name":"Kelly","last_name":"Fuller","email":"kfullerf@tripod.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"199.209.173.51"},
{"id":17,"first_name":"Frank","last_name":"Cook","email":"fcookg@google.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"58.30.243.1"},
{"id":18,"first_name":"Alan","last_name":"Rice","email":"ariceh@sciencedirect.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"44.231.199.117"},
{"id":19,"first_name":"Mark","last_name":"Greene","email":"mgreenei@paypal.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"45.34.44.2"},
{"id":20,"first_name":"Charles","last_name":"King","email":"ckingj@clickbank.net","gender":"Male","ip_address":"237.30.205.186"}];

            var tr;
           
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append('<td class="name" rel="' + val.first_name + '">' + val.first_name + '</td>');
                $('table').append(tr);
            });
        });
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;

}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background:#2cc3ce;
  color:#0d3852;
}

/* demo styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: #0d3852;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}

input {
    max-width:50px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ac-custom {
 padding: 0 1em;
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.ac-custom h2 {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 margin: 0 0 30px;
 color:#0d3852;
}

.ac-custom ul,
.ac-custom ol {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 800px;
}

.ac-custom li {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0.5em 0;
 position: relative;
}

.ac-custom label {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: 0 0 0 80px;
 vertical-align: top;
 color: #0d3852;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"],
.ac-custom label::before {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 z-index: 100;
}

.ac-custom label::before {
 content: '';
 border: 1px solid #0d3852;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.ac-radio label::before {
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 color: #fff;
} 

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

/* General SVG and path styles */

.ac-custom svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -12px;
 left: 0px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.ac-custom svg path {
 stroke: #0d3852;
 stroke-width: 13px;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 fill: none;
}

/* Specific input, SVG and path styles */

/* Circle */
.ac-circle input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-circle input[type="radio"],
.ac-circle label::before {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: -15px;
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}

.ac-circle label::before {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: none;
}

.ac-circle svg {
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin-top: -35px;
 left: -10px;
}

.ac-circle svg path {
 stroke-width: 5px;
} 

/* Box Fill */
.ac-boxfill svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
} 

/* Swirl */
.ac-swirl svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
}

/* List */
.ac-list ol {
 list-style: decimal;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

.ac-list ol li {
 font-size: 2em;
 padding: 1em 1em 0 2em;
 text-indent: -40px;
}

.ac-list ol li label {
 font-size: 0.5em;
 text-indent: 0;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.ac-list label::before {
 display: none;
}

.ac-list svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 left: 0;
 top: 1.2em;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.ac-list svg path {
 stroke-width: 4px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top:0;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    float: left;
  }

  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  } 
 
 .filter-columns {
 background-color:#2cc3ce;
 }
 
 .filter-columns-alt {
 background-color:#78D9E0;
 min-height:256px;
 }

ul,li { 
 margin:0; 
 padding:0; 
 list-style:none;
}

.label {
  color:#000;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr id="ProductID" class="first">
        <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a function to include or do I have to include a statement? Also, please note that I want the code to be fast in a way and not really slow.

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Do not include 2 versions of jQuery.

Comment: You should use a templating laguage

Comment: @SLaks If I do not include both, then the code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the first name, you can add each name to an indexed array and only print the name if it is not already in the indexed array. Adding four lines to your code will achieve this.

```
       var tr;
       var alreadyused = []; //This creates an array
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if ($.inArray(val.first_name, alreadyused) == -1) { // This checks if first name already in array
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append('<td class="name" rel="' + val.first_name + '">' + val.first_name + '</td>');
                $('table').append(tr);
                alreadyused.push(val.first_name); // This adds firstname to array           
            }
        });
    });
```

If you are going to end up doing it with more than one of the fields, it would probably be best to use a multidimensional associative array.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to `filter` the `json` array, using an `associative` array.

```
var seenNames = {};
data = data.filter(function(currentObject) {
    if (currentObject.first_name in seenNames) { //Checks if first_name already in array.
       return false;
    } else {
       seenNames[currentObject.first_name] = true;
       return true;
    } 
});
```

```js
$(function() { 
    var data = [{"id":2.2,"first_name":"Debra","last_name":"Rodriguez","email":"drodriguez0@admin.ch","gender":"Female","ip_address":"90.22.159.108"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Julie","last_name":"Lynch","email":"jlynch1@tumblr.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"54.182.62.180"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Norma","last_name":"Washington","email":"nwashington2@theatlantic.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"70.163.106.64"},
{"id":4,"first_name":"Bobby","last_name":"Castillo","email":"bcastillo3@nbcnews.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"91.202.59.171"},
{"id":5,"first_name":"Henry","last_name":"Chavez","email":"hchavez4@chronoengine.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"32.237.37.185"},
{"id":6,"first_name":"Debra","last_name":"Howard","email":"showard5@stumbleupon.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"17.217.42.49"},
{"id":7,"first_name":"Jason","last_name":"Powell","email":"jpowell6@telegraph.co.uk","gender":"Male","ip_address":"14.81.195.117"},
{"id":8,"first_name":"Sean","last_name":"Burns","email":"sburns7@hp.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"213.164.85.212"},
{"id":9,"first_name":"Jacqueline","last_name":"Gordon","email":"jgordon8@bloglines.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"18.251.62.55"},
{"id":10,"first_name":"Russell","last_name":"Richards","email":"rrichards9@com.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"27.226.59.80"},
{"id":11,"first_name":"Albert","last_name":"Perkins","email":"aperkinsa@hc360.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"243.122.251.248"},
{"id":12,"first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Willis","email":"mwillisb@deviantart.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"252.197.211.230"},
{"id":13,"first_name":"Joan","last_name":"Hamilton","email":"jhamiltonc@weebly.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"204.70.110.117"},
{"id":14,"first_name":"Eric","last_name":"Garcia","email":"egarciad@yahoo.co.jp","gender":"Male","ip_address":"178.221.216.3"},
{"id":15,"first_name":"Frank","last_name":"Olson","email":"folsone@amazon.co.uk","gender":"Male","ip_address":"245.25.170.33"},
{"id":16,"first_name":"Kelly","last_name":"Fuller","email":"kfullerf@tripod.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"199.209.173.51"},
{"id":17,"first_name":"Frank","last_name":"Cook","email":"fcookg@google.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"58.30.243.1"},
{"id":18,"first_name":"Alan","last_name":"Rice","email":"ariceh@sciencedirect.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"44.231.199.117"},
{"id":19,"first_name":"Mark","last_name":"Greene","email":"mgreenei@paypal.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"45.34.44.2"},
{"id":20,"first_name":"Charles","last_name":"King","email":"ckingj@clickbank.net","gender":"Male","ip_address":"237.30.205.186"}];
var seenNames = {};
data = data.filter(function(currentObject) {
    if (currentObject.first_name in seenNames) {
        return false;
    } else {
        seenNames[currentObject.first_name] = true;
        return true;
    }
});
            var tr;
           
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append('<td class="name" rel="' + val.first_name + '">' + val.first_name + '</td>');
                $('table').append(tr);
            });
        });
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;

}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background:#2cc3ce;
  color:#0d3852;
}

/* demo styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: #0d3852;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}

input {
    max-width:50px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ac-custom {
 padding: 0 1em;
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.ac-custom h2 {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 margin: 0 0 30px;
 color:#0d3852;
}

.ac-custom ul,
.ac-custom ol {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 800px;
}

.ac-custom li {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0.5em 0;
 position: relative;
}

.ac-custom label {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: 0 0 0 80px;
 vertical-align: top;
 color: #0d3852;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"],
.ac-custom label::before {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 z-index: 100;
}

.ac-custom label::before {
 content: '';
 border: 1px solid #0d3852;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.ac-radio label::before {
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 color: #fff;
} 

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

/* General SVG and path styles */

.ac-custom svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -12px;
 left: 0px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.ac-custom svg path {
 stroke: #0d3852;
 stroke-width: 13px;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 fill: none;
}

/* Specific input, SVG and path styles */

/* Circle */
.ac-circle input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-circle input[type="radio"],
.ac-circle label::before {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: -15px;
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}

.ac-circle label::before {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: none;
}

.ac-circle svg {
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin-top: -35px;
 left: -10px;
}

.ac-circle svg path {
 stroke-width: 5px;
} 

/* Box Fill */
.ac-boxfill svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
} 

/* Swirl */
.ac-swirl svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
}

/* List */
.ac-list ol {
 list-style: decimal;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

.ac-list ol li {
 font-size: 2em;
 padding: 1em 1em 0 2em;
 text-indent: -40px;
}

.ac-list ol li label {
 font-size: 0.5em;
 text-indent: 0;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.ac-list label::before {
 display: none;
}

.ac-list svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 left: 0;
 top: 1.2em;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.ac-list svg path {
 stroke-width: 4px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top:0;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    float: left;
  }

  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  } 
 
 .filter-columns {
 background-color:#2cc3ce;
 }
 
 .filter-columns-alt {
 background-color:#78D9E0;
 min-height:256px;
 }

ul,li { 
 margin:0; 
 padding:0; 
 list-style:none;
}

.label {
  color:#000;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr id="ProductID" class="first">
        <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> </tbody>
</table>
```